# Swift 2.0 tuple, many assignments

Tags: swift2, tuples, dropbox-api

```
if let (metadata, url) = response, data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), image = UIImage(data: data) {
```

sources: https://github.com/dropbox/PhotoWatch/blob/master/PhotoWatch/PhotoViewController.swift

I’m a little confused by this syntax and was wondering if anyone could help me get it.

​*What I get:*​ I understand that `if let` is assigning a value to a variable if the value exist and `(metadata, url)` is a tuple.

​*What I don’t get:*​ with three equals and many commas what values are getting assigned where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if let` code snippet illustrates horrible, unreadable code formatting.  One proper formatting is:

```
if let (metadata, url) = response, 
    data  = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), 
    image = UIImage(data: data) {
  // Use the four bound variables
}
else {
  // One or more of the four are nil
}
```

The `if let` syntactic form will execute the 'consequent' if all bound variables are not `nil`; otherwise the 'alternate' is executed.

The `if let` syntax with `,` is newer Swift syntax.  It used to be that only one assignment at a time was possible.  People wrote code like this:

```
if let (metadata, url) = response {
  if let data  = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
      // Use the four bound variables
    }
// lots of `else` clauses; a big mess...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is just big multiple assignment (3 variables):

```
(metadata, url) = response, data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), image = UIImage(data: data)
```

(metadata, url) is getting "response", data "NSData(contentsOfURL: url)" and image "UIImage(data: data)"

It is convenient because it is possible to use the variables immediately after the declaration/assignment.

The "if" clause is looking for the whole assignment, as if it was a single one.